# How do I access other users' AWS Lambda Test Events as root user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I'm logging into AWS using my main account as the root user (which may or may not be a bad idea ultimately, but for now it's fine). When I head over to the Lambda and look at Test Events, I cannot see the test events that other IAM users have created. It would make sense that an IAM user couldn't see the root user's assets, but I'm confused as to why I as root user don't have access to their assets.

In short, I want to be able to run tests using the events someone else created (and vice versa), but I can't see them. I don't want myself (and anyone else) to have to replicate all tests that others create since they are useful for all of us in collaboration and testing.

It seems weird that I can access/edit/run the Lambda functions etc, but not the test events. I also tried creating a new IAM user and copying the permissions of another user and I still don't have access to their test events.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Lambda test events are specific to a logged-in console user and cannot be shared across users.

If I recall, these events were originally stored in browser local storage which meant that a given user couldn't go to another browser or another machine and retrieve the events. That changed with this [Improved Testing on the AWS Lambda Console](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/improved-testing-on-the-aws-lambda-console/) announcement and now they are persistent for the logged-in user so you can go to another browser or machine. But they're not sharable and, afaik, there is no API that will retrieve them for you.

A better solution, in my opinion, would be to revision-control a small number of scripts that invoke Lambda functions with known payloads. This could be part of your repo's test suite and shared across a team.

Answer (score 0):

Since March of this year, this is now possible to share test events within the same account with different users.

The announcement: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/03/aws-lambda-console-test-events/

The doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/testing-functions.html#creating-shareable-events

Answer (score 0):

A schema defines the structure of events that are sent to EventBridge. EventBridge provides schemas for all events that are generated by AWS services.

To enable sharing this Lambda Test Event you could do several steps.

1. You should enable or attach AmazonEventBridgeSchemasFullAccess Policy to the IAM user or User Groups.
2. Then on Function and Under Test Event Form, do the following:

   - Under Event sharing settings, choose Shareable.

Your saved test should be access by other IAM users.